# Why does Adaptive Card Input.Date subtract 1 day from the selected date?

Tags: date, datepicker, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Using botframework with msteams channel.

[image]

The adaptive card. Nothing special, just a few textblocks and date inputs. The input values are saved to memory.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "style": "emphasis",
          "width": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Please enter the information below",
              "size": "Large"
            },
            {
              "type": "Container",
              "style": "emphasis",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "End Of Last Month",
                  "wrap": true
                },
                {
                  "type": "Input.Date",                  
                  "id": "Date_EndOfLastMonth",
                  "value": "${dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastMonth}",
                  "placeholder": ""
                },
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "${dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastMonthError}",
                  "size": "small",
                  "wrap": true,
                  "color": "attention"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Container",
              "style": "emphasis",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "End Of Last Year",
                  "wrap": true
                },
                {
                  "type": "Input.Date",                  
                  "id": "Date_EndOfLastYear",
                  "value": "${dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastYear}",
                  "placeholder": ""
                },
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "${dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastYearError}",
                  "size": "small",
                  "wrap": true,
                  "color": "attention"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Container",
              "style": "emphasis",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Valuation Key Date",
                  "wrap": true
                },
                {
                  "type": "Input.Date",                  
                  "id": "ValuationKeyDate",
                  "value": "${dialog.requestForm.ValuationKeyDate}",
                  "placeholder": ""
                },
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "${dialog.requestForm.ValuationKeyDateError}",
                  "size": "small",
                  "wrap": true,
                  "color": "attention"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Container",
              "style": "emphasis",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "ActionSet",
                  "actions": [
                    {
                      "type": "Action.Submit",
                      "title": "Submit",
                      "data": {
                        "msteams": {
                          "type": "messageBack",
                          "displayText": "Form Submitted",
                          "text": "submitform"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The code that goes with the card. I save the input values to memory, so when there is a reprompt happening, I can fill them back to the form. In the last part are the lines for debugging. I am printing out the values directly from the activity, so nothing happens between the submission and the debug.

```
new CodeAction(async (dc, options) =>
                            {
                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastMonth", "");
                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastYear", "");
                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm.ValuationKeyDate", ""); //ValuationKeyDate

                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastMonthError", "");
                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm.Date_EndOfLastYearError", "");
                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm.ValuationKeyDateError", "");

                                return await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                            }),
                            new TextInput()
                            {
                                Id = "repromptTRT",
                                Prompt = new ActivityTemplate("${TreasuryCase()}"),
                                AllowInterruptions = true,
                                MaxTurnCount = "if(turn.activity.text != 'submitform', '0', '100')",
                            },                            
                            // deal with interrupt, cancel everything else                            
                            new IfCondition()
                            {
                                Condition = "turn.activity.text != 'submitform'",
                                Actions = new List<Dialog>()
                                {
                                    new EndDialog()
                                }
                            },
                            // save form
                            new CodeAction(async (dc, options) =>
                            {
                                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dc.Context.Activity.Value);

                                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(json));

                                var d = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);

                                await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(d));

                                var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TC>(json);                                

                                dc.State.SetValue("dialog.requestForm", o);

                                return await dc.EndDialogAsync();
                            }),
```

Comment: Are you doing any date manipulation logic in your code?

Comment: @VinothRajendran No. What you see down there is the value of dc.Context.Activity.Value, and on the bottom is the actual datetime. And I think it isn't even a date, but a string.

Comment: Can you share your adaptive card? Does this happen in other channels, outside of MSTeams?

Comment: @DanaV I have shared the card code and the C# code in the edit. This card works only in teams because of the specialized submit action.

Comment: @AronGaborKelsch: This is a Bug in Teams which is reproducible with specific date format. So, you may need to wait for fix rollout.

Comment: @SubbaReddiTummuru Is there a way to work around it? Is there a thread for this fix or a description of the problem?

Comment: @AronGaborKelsch: Here is the thread: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/4355

Comment: @AronGaborKelsch,The fix should be rolling through the rings, so the change should manifest in public clients in a couple of weeks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more visibility, adding answer here from comment section:
The fix should be rolling through the rings, so the change should manifest in public clients in a couple of weeks.

Comment: This issue is on and off now. Me and my users are on the same tenant, however on my machine the problem still persists. The users have reported the issue disappearing and reappearing again. How does this work then?

Comment: Yes, we have informed Engineering team about the same and they are currently working on the fix. We will inform you once we have further update. Thanks!

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed now. Please verify